# Enable graphical login in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: login, graphical-user-interface, ubuntu-12.04

Ubuntu has been installed in VMWare using easy install (or something sounding like this). Therefore the OS starts now in text mode and to access GUI I have to type startx.

How to enable the GUI with graphical login screen?

**/etc/default/grub** file has following values inside:

```
....
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
....
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

so it corresponds to recommendations how to turn graphical login on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grub configuration is only to do with actually booting the system. Once the kernel is loaded, that takes over.

The answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/142339/gdm-wont-automatically-start-after-boot) suggests trying `sudo apt-get -f install gdm` in case the installation has dependency problems or checking `/etc/init/gdm.conf` for start up rules.